# Vampire stage 4 and I can't feed myself

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've become a vampire and I've started the quest to cure myself. As I'm stage 4, I can't talk to Falion, so I've tried to drink some blood around. I've done 3-4 humans and it seems not to be enough. People still want to kill me all the time.

What did I do wrong and what should I do? I'm playing on a PS3.

Answer (score 2):

One feeding is enough to reduce your vampirism to stage 1 regardless of how long it has been since you had a "snack". The ongoing hostility is either due to people witnessing / remembering your violent tendencies or a bug.

If you fast travel to somewhere you have no bounty in after feeding and the people are still hostile, reload an old save or get the dawnguard expansion(it removes the stage 4 vampire hostility).

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of suggestions on [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_%28Skyrim%29#Curing_vampirism)

Doesn't say how many feedings you need however you can feed multiple times off the same sleeping person.

Personally, I just became a werewolf.